# Can I scp a folder that has sub folders?

Tags: ubuntu, scp

I have a folder that contains files for a static website like:

```
/site/index.html
/site/css/css.css
/site/js/js.js
/site/images/...
```

If I update something on my laptop, I want a single command to send the files off to my ubuntu server.  I don't want to setup FTP on it if I don't have too, wondering if scp would be able to handle this?

Comment: I prefer `tar` via `ssh`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10028/79839

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The command `scp -r source user@target:dest` will walk all subdirectories of *source* and copy them.

However, `scp` behaves like `cp` and always copies files, even if it is the same on both source and destination. [See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/scp-without-replacing-existing-files-in-the-destination) for a workaround.]

As this is a static website, you are most likely only making updates, not re-creating the whole thing, so you will probably find things move along faster if you use `rsync` over ssh instead of `scp`.  Probably something like

```
rsync -av -e ssh source user@target:dest
```

...to get started.  If you are doing this across a LAN, I would personally use the options `-avW` instead for `rsync`.

Rsync also gives you the ability to duplicate deletions in your source; so if you remove a file from your tree, you can run `rsync` as above, and include the flag `--delete` and it will remove the same file from the destination side.

Answer (score 10):

scp has a recursive flag that will do what you want. `scp -r /base/directory user@server:/to/location`

from `man scp`

> ```
> -r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows symbolic
>           links encountered in the tree traversal.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

scp -r and rsync -r are the most reliable ways to get what you want, as others have noted.

You can also use sshfs to 'mount' it as if it were a local drive: `sshfs user@host:/site /mnt/mountpoint`

(However you're probably better off working locally and deploying with rsync. Just another tool to be aware of.)

Answer (score 0):

Use below command

> scp -r *sourceFolder* username@server:*destinationFolder*